# Prove the dimension of a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ is a vector space over a field F, has dimension $d$. Then I think it is natural to consider $F$ is a vector space over its subfield $S\subset F$ because it satisfies the following properties,
$$
x + y \in F \\
c\cdot x\in F
$$
for $x, y\in F$ and $c\in S$. Now suppose we say that the vector space ($F$ over $S$) above has dimension n, then how to explain if the vector space V over this subfield $S\subset F$, inherited the addition and scalar multiplication from $V$ over $F$, has dimension $n\cdot d$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty simple: by hypothesis, $F\simeq_S S^n$ and $V\simeq_F F^d$, so
$$V\simeq_S\bigl(S^n\bigr)^d \simeq_S S^{nd}.$$

Comment: I am new to this topic, so would you mind explaining how the above is satisfied? Particularly, is it possible to explain this with respect to the dimension of basis?

Comment: Well, in the case of $V$ as an $F$-vector space, once you have a basis with $d$ vectors, each vector is entirely determined by its set of $d$ coordinates in the basis, and the isomorphism with $F^d$ maps each vector $v\in V$ onto its set of coordinates, which is an element of $F^d$. Similarly with $F$ as an $S$-vector space. Is that clearer?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, I wonder if it is equivalent to say that since $V$ over $F$ has dimension $d$ and $F$ over $S$ has dimension $n$, then a vector in the basis of $V$ over $F$ can be expressed as the sum of $d$ vectors in the basis of $F$ over $S$. So, as a result $V$ over $S$ has dimension $d\cdot n$.

Comment: Actually, each  vector in the basis of $V$ (over $F$) has to be multiplied by each vector of a basis of $F$ over $S$, so you obtain a basis of $V$ over $S$, comprising $nd$ vectors. . Think of a complex vector space, seen as an $\mathbf R$-vector space

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand  " each vector in the basis of V (over F) has to be multiplied by each vector of a basis of F over S," what do you mean by "multiplied"? Can you give a simple example？

Comment: Yes. Consider a $2$-dimensional complex vector space $V$, with basis $\{v_1, v_2\}$. A basis of $\mathbf C$ over $\mathbf R$ is $\{1,i\}$. We obtain $\{v_1, iv_1, v_2,iv_2\}$ as a basis of $V$ over $\mathbf R$.

Comment: That is very helpful, thanks. But let me present it using your example to see if I understand it correctly. So because any vector in $V$ over $C$ can be expressed as the sum $a\cdot v_1+b\cdot v_2$, for $a, b\in C$ and any vector in $C$ can be expressed as the sum $j\cdot 1 + k\cdot i$ for $j, k \in R$. Therefore any vector in $V$ can be expressed as the sum $(j\cdot 1 + k\cdot i) \cdot v_1 + (s\cdot 1 + t\cdot i)\cdot v_2 = j\cdot v_1 + k\cdot iv_1 + s\cdot v_2 + t\cdot iv_2$ for $j, k, s, t\in R$. Therefore a basis of $V$ over $R$ is $\{v_1, iv_1, v_2, iv_2\}$.

Comment: This is similar to the question I asked and hence $V$ over $S$ has dimension $n\cdot d$. Thank you so much, really appreciate it.

Comment: You've got it. Strictly speaking, one should also prove the $4$ vectors are linearly independent over $\mathbf R$  (your argument on ly shows it is a spanning set), but it is not hard.